# Get SelectedValue from listbox on longpress contextMenu click in windowsphone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

i am trying to get SelectedValue for selected item in listbox and then perform action to get id from database. Below is the code I am trying on Context Menu long press

```
var selected = (NewsData)lstNews.SelectedValue;
int a = selected.newsID;
MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
```

but than it throws error.

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. this is because we can get selectedvalue only on select tap event but how to achieve same on long press context menu click event .

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: i know it is null but if i use same code on select tap event it works fine .i want it to work on longpress contextmenu click @SonerGönül

Comment: I suspect context menu click action doesn't set `SelectedValue` by default, you can use `sender` parameter instead. Post relevant XAML markup, particularly the listbox.

Comment: how to do that?? @har07

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that's because context menu click action doesn't set `SelectedValue` by default. You can get information that correspond to clicked item from `sender` parameter instead, for example (assuming that the `ListBox` markup looks like the one posted in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119367/delete-selected-item-from-listbox-in-windowsphone-using-c-sharp)) :

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    var ctxMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
    var stackpanel = (StackPanel)ctxMenu.Owner;
    var selected = (NewsData)stackpanel.DataContext;
    int a = selected.newsID;
    MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
}
```